# How to turn a tar file to a tgz file?

Tags: tar, gzip

I usually create a tgz file for `my_files` with the command `tar -czvf my_files.tgz my_files`, and extract them with `tar -zxvf my_files.tgz`. Now I have a tar file created with the command `tar -cvf my_files.tar my_files`. I'm wondering how I can turn the `my_files.tar` into `my_files.tgz` so that later I can extract it with the command `tar -zxvf my_files.tgz`? Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A plain `.tar` archive created with `cf` (with or without `v`) is uncompressed; to get a `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` archive, compress it:

```
gzip < my_files.tar > my_files.tgz
```

You might want to add `-9` for better compression:

```
gzip -9 < my_files.tar > my_files.tgz
```

Both variants will leave both archives around; you can use

```
gzip -9 my_files.tar
```

instead, which will produce `my_files.tar.gz` and delete `my_files.tar` (if everything goes well). You can then rename `my_files.tar.gz` to `my_files.tgz` if you wish.

With many `tar` implementations you can extract archives without specifying the `z` option, and `tar` will figure out what to do — so you can use the same command with compressed and uncompressed archives.

Comment: How about the reverse? tar.gz into tar?

Comment: @benathon `gunzip < my_files.tar.gz > my_files.tar`, or `gunzip my_files.tar.gz` if you don’t want to keep the compressed archive.